# needs to select at least one form-control in the prefix and suffix From the forms set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here I have a situation like user needs to select at least one form control in between suffix or prefix and rest all doesn't matter but user needs to select compulsory one in between suffix or prefix. How can be implemented in angular.

configGroup: FormGroup;

```
    <div class="cred-ref-id-wrap">
                    <label for="prefix"
                        [invalid]="(!configGroup?.controls?.prefix?.pristine) && (!configGroup?.controls?.prefix?.valid)">
                         prefix
                        <input
                              [formControlName]="'prefix'" 
                              [placeholder]="'release"
                              [autocomplete]="'off'"
                              (focusout)="getValue('prefix')">
                    </label>
    </div>

   <div class="cred-ref-id-wrap">
                    <label for="suffix"
                        [invalid]="(!configGroup?.controls?.suffix?.pristine) && (!configGroup?.controls?.suffix?.valid)">
                         suffix
                        <input
                              [formControlName]="'suffix'" 
                              [placeholder]="'release"
                              [autocomplete]="'off'"
                              (focusout)="getValue('suffix')">
                    </label>
    </div>

           
            this.configGroup = new FormGroup({
                      accountOne: new FormControl(null),
                      accountTwo: new FormControl(null),
            
                      prefix: new FormControl(""),
                      suffix: new FormControl(""),
            
                      critical: new FormControl(null),
                      medium: new FormControl(null),
                      low: new FormControl(null),
                      none: new FormControl(null)
                   });
```

Here i have tried like below but it's not working:

```
suffixOrPrefixValidator = (formGroup: FormGroup): null => {
      const prefix = this.configGroup.controls.prefix;
      const suffix = this.configGroup.controls.suffix;
      if (!prefix.value && !suffix.value) {
          formGroup.controls.prefix.setErrors({ suffixOrPrefix: true });
          formGroup.controls.suffix.setErrors({ suffixOrPrefix: true });
      } else {
          formGroup.controls.prefix.setErrors(null);
          formGroup.controls.suffix.setErrors(null);
      }
      return null;
  };
         this.configGroup = new FormGroup({
              account: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
              organization: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        
              variable: new FormControl("",this.suffixOrPrefixValidator),
              prefix: new FormControl("",this.suffixOrPrefixValidator),
        
              sev1: new FormControl(null),
              sev2: new FormControl(null),
              sev3: new FormControl(null),
              sev4: new FormControl(null)
            });
```